# Battleship Code Too Many Hits

Tags: java, arrays

This project was to make a 2d battleship project using arrays. If you hit, it makes an "X." If it's one slot away up, down, right, or left, it is "H" for hot. If it's two slots away, it's "W" for warm. "C" for cool for three slots, and miss for everything else. 
Every time I go to test out my code, it works for the first time perfectly fine, but afterwards it marks every input as a hit, when it should mark it as "H", "W", "C", or "M."

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Battleship
{
public static void main ()
{
    int rowLoc = 0;
    int colLoc = 0;
    int rowGuess;
    int colGuess;
    int guesses = 1;
    int shipNum = 5;
    //variable declaration

    String[][] battleGrid = new String[10][10];
    String[][] battleGridKnown = new String[10][10];
    //grid declaration

    System.out.println("Welcome to Battleship!\nFive ships are hidden in row 0-9 and columns 0-9.");
    System.out.println("After each guess, you will been told if your guess was...");
    System.out.println("- Hit (X)\n- Close (H for hot)\n- Somewhat close (W for warm)\n- Not that close (C for cool)\n- Miss (M)."); 
    //welcome message
    for (int r = 0; r < battleGrid.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < battleGrid[r].length; c++)
        {
            battleGrid[r][c] = "-";
        }
    }
    //initializes what is in battleGrid by default
    for (int r = 0; r < battleGridKnown.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < battleGridKnown[r].length; c++)
        {
            battleGridKnown[r][c] = "-";
        }
    }
    //initializes what is in battleGridKnown by default
    for (int k = 1; k <= shipNum; k++)
    {
        do
        {
            rowLoc = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 0);
            colLoc = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 0);    
        } while(battleGrid[rowLoc][colLoc] == "S");
        battleGrid[rowLoc][colLoc] = "S";     
    }
    //sets ships and also the stuff around the ships
    /*for (int r = 0; r < battleGrid.length; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < battleGrid[r].length; c++)
                {
                    System.out.print(battleGrid[r][c] + "");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            //test printer*/
    while(shipNum > 0)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter your row guess (0-9): ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        rowGuess = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter your column guess (0-9): ");
        colGuess = in.nextInt();
        // enter row + column guesses
        if (battleGrid[rowGuess][colGuess] == battleGrid[rowLoc][colLoc])
        {
            shipNum--;
            battleGridKnown[rowGuess][colGuess] = "X";
            System.out.println("Hit! There are " + shipNum + " ships remaining.");
            System.out.println("Guess attempt number: " + guesses + ".");
            for (int r = 0; r < battleGridKnown.length; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < battleGridKnown[r].length; c++)
                {
                    System.out.print(battleGridKnown[r][c] + "");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else if(rowGuess == rowLoc-- || rowGuess == rowLoc++ || colGuess == colLoc-- || colGuess == colLoc++)
        {
            battleGridKnown[rowGuess][colGuess] = "H";
            System.out.println("Hot!");
            System.out.println("Guess attempt number: " + guesses + ".");
            for (int r = 0; r < battleGridKnown.length; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < battleGridKnown[r].length; c++)
                {
                    System.out.print(battleGridKnown[r][c] + "");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else if(rowGuess == rowLoc - 2 || rowGuess == rowLoc + 2 || colGuess == colLoc - 2 || colGuess == colLoc + 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Warm...");
            battleGridKnown[rowGuess][colGuess] = "W";
            System.out.println("Guess attempt number: " + guesses + ".");
            for (int r = 0; r < battleGridKnown.length; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < battleGridKnown[r].length; c++)
                {        
                    System.out.print(battleGridKnown[r][c] + "");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else if(rowGuess == rowLoc - 3 || rowGuess == rowLoc + 3 || colGuess == colLoc - 3 || colGuess == colLoc + 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Cool...");
            battleGridKnown[rowGuess][colGuess] = "C";
            System.out.println("Guess attempt number: " + guesses + ".");
            for (int r = 0; r < battleGridKnown.length; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < battleGridKnown[r].length; c++)
                {
                    System.out.print(battleGridKnown[r][c] + "");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Miss.");
            System.out.println("Guess attempt number: " + guesses + ".");
            for (int r = 0; r < battleGridKnown.length; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < battleGridKnown[r].length; c++)
                {
                    battleGridKnown[rowGuess][colGuess] = "M";
                    System.out.print(battleGridKnown[r][c] + "");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        guesses++;
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing!\nYou found all the ships in " + guesses + " guesses.");
}
```

}

Comment: Best thing to do would be to step through this with a debugger.

Comment: You might also want to put common code into functions to make your program easier to understand. For example, the code that prints out `battleGridKnown` appears five times.

Comment: I would suggest you to go for MCV. Model object, view object and controller object. Through this your game would be easier to write and understandable. And I think this is the sample game from the book head first javascript.

Comment: @Lokesh The MVC pattern doesn't fit the architecture of games for the most part, [see this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/why-are-mvc-tdd-not-employed-more-in-game-architecture). While I use MVC all the time in web development with database, I never had a need to use it in game development.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I understand but for this game it would be simple to implement.

Comment: @Lokesh We're dealing with someone who is still putting all their code in `main()`, so your suggestion might be too advanced.